# Logging Payload of POSTs to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I've managed to enable access logging in Tomcat by editing the conf/server.xml and uncommenting the entry for the org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve Valve. I'd like to be able to dump the contents of POST's payload. It doesn't seem like any of the options in the pattern will do this. Is there a built in way to do this? Do I use the AccessLogValve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there was not a suggestion of a built in way to get the POST payload, I went ahead and wrote a custom filter that dumps the contents of the payload. Specifically:

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    LOG.debug("payload: " + requestWrapper.getRequestBody());
```

and `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.host.PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Where does the `requestWrapper` come from? Or is that supposed to be the `request` object?

Comment: requestWrapper comes from here aka MyRequestWrapper. it works! http://natch3z.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html

Comment: Where should I put "public void doFilter(..." ?

Answer (score 4):

If the post is a form (application/x-www-urlencoded), you can use ExtendedAccessLogValve,

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ExtendedAccessLogValve.html

You have to select individual parameters in the pattern like this,

```
  x-P(param_name)
```

Comment: @ZZ: what if it is not a form?

Comment: If it's not a form, you can't really log the post body. The log format is defined by http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html. It doesn't support arbitrary post body, which can be binary and huge, in case of file upload.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case for me. I'm not posting content as parameters, though the payload size will not likely be more than a few kb.

Comment: Post payload doesn't belong to logs. You need to dump it somewhere else in your server.

Comment: Which is fine, but I want to be able to associate the access information for it. Is there some trick to doing this without writing a custom Valve or the like?

Comment: I don't think you will find anything inside Tomcat. If this is indeed for logging, you need to come up with a log format and hex-dump the request in your server. If it's for debugging, use Wireshark or Fiddler to watch the post body.

Answer (score 4):

1. In your webapp web.xml add:

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>your.MyLogFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/path/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. Create your Filter:

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.util.Enumeration;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Locale;
   import java.util.Map;

   import javax.servlet.Filter;
   import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
   import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
   import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
   import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
   import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;

   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
   import com.liferay.util.servlet.ServletInputStreamWrapper;

   public class MyLogFilter implements Filter {

       private static final Log logger = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyLogFilter.class);

       @Override
       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
       }

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
               FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           try {
               HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
               HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

               Map<String, String> requestMap = this.getTypesafeRequestMap(httpServletRequest);
               BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedReqest = new BufferedRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
               BufferedResponseWrapper bufferedResponse = new BufferedResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

               chain.doFilter(bufferedReqest, bufferedResponse);

               if(bufferedResponse.getContent()!=null){    //Response
                   final StringBuilder resMessage = new StringBuilder();
                   resMessage.append(" [RESPONSE:")
                           .append(bufferedResponse.getContent() )
                           .append("]");
                   logger.info(resMessage);
               }
               else{ //Request
                   final StringBuilder reqMessage = new StringBuilder(
                           "REST Request - ").append("[HTTP METHOD:")
                           .append(httpServletRequest.getMethod())
                           .append("] [PATH INFO:")
                           .append(httpServletRequest.getPathInfo())
                           .append("] [REQUEST PARAMETERS:").append(requestMap)
                           .append("] [REQUEST BODY:")
                           .append(bufferedReqest.getRequestBody())
                           .append("] [REMOTE ADDRESS:")
                           .append(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()).append("]");
                   logger.info(reqMessage);
               }


           } catch (Throwable a) {
               logger.error(a);
           }
       }

       private Map<String, String> getTypesafeRequestMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
           Map<String, String> typesafeRequestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
           Enumeration<?> requestParamNames = request.getParameterNames();
           while (requestParamNames.hasMoreElements()) {
               String requestParamName = (String) requestParamNames.nextElement();
               String requestParamValue = request.getParameter(requestParamName);
               typesafeRequestMap.put(requestParamName, requestParamValue);
           }
           return typesafeRequestMap;
       }

       @Override
       public void destroy() {
       }

       private static final class BufferedRequestWrapper extends
               HttpServletRequestWrapper {

           private ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
           private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
           private BufferedServletInputStream bsis = null;
           private byte[] buffer = null;

           public BufferedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest req)
                   throws IOException {
               super(req);
               // Read InputStream and store its content in a buffer.
               InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
               this.baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
               int letti;
               while ((letti = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                   this.baos.write(buf, 0, letti);
               }
               this.buffer = this.baos.toByteArray();
           }

           @Override
           public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
               this.bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.buffer);
               this.bsis = new BufferedServletInputStream(this.bais);

               return this.bsis;
           }

           @Override
           public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
               return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
           }

           String getRequestBody() throws IOException {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       this.getInputStream()));
               String line = null;
               StringBuilder inputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
               do {
                   line = reader.readLine();
                   if (null != line) {
                       inputBuffer.append(line.trim());
                   }
               } while (line != null);
               reader.close();
               return inputBuffer.toString().trim();
           }

       }

       private static final class BufferedServletInputStream extends
               ServletInputStream {

           private ByteArrayInputStream bais;

           public BufferedServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
               this.bais = bais;
           }

           @Override
           public int available() {
               return this.bais.available();
           }

           @Override
           public int read() {
               return this.bais.read();
           }

           @Override
           public int read(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
               return this.bais.read(buf, off, len);
           }

       }

       public class TeeServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

           private final TeeOutputStream targetStream;

           public TeeServletOutputStream(OutputStream one, OutputStream two) {
               targetStream = new TeeOutputStream(one, two);
           }

           @Override
           public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
               this.targetStream.write(arg0);
           }

           public void flush() throws IOException {
               super.flush();
               this.targetStream.flush();
           }

           public void close() throws IOException {
               super.close();
               this.targetStream.close();
           }
       }

       public class BufferedResponseWrapper implements HttpServletResponse {

           HttpServletResponse original;
           TeeServletOutputStream teeStream;
           PrintWriter teeWriter;
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos;

           public BufferedResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
               original = response;
           }

           public String getContent() {
               if(bos == null){
                   return null;
               }
               return bos.toString();
           }

           @Override
           public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {

               if (this.teeWriter == null) {
                   this.teeWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                           getOutputStream()));
               }
               return this.teeWriter;
           }

           @Override
           public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {

               if (teeStream == null) {
                   bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   teeStream = new TeeServletOutputStream(
                           original.getOutputStream(), bos);
               }
               return teeStream;
           }

           @Override
           public String getCharacterEncoding() {
               return original.getCharacterEncoding();
           }

           @Override
           public String getContentType() {
               return original.getContentType();
           }

           @Override
           public void setCharacterEncoding(String charset) {
               original.setCharacterEncoding(charset);
           }

           @Override
           public void setContentLength(int len) {
               original.setContentLength(len);
           }

           @Override
           public void setContentType(String type) {
               original.setContentType(type);
           }

           @Override
           public void setBufferSize(int size) {
               original.setBufferSize(size);
           }

           @Override
           public int getBufferSize() {
               return original.getBufferSize();
           }

           @Override
           public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
               if (teeStream != null) {
                   teeStream.flush();
               }
               if (this.teeWriter != null) {
                   this.teeWriter.flush();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void resetBuffer() {
               original.resetBuffer();
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isCommitted() {
               return original.isCommitted();
           }

           @Override
           public void reset() {
               original.reset();
           }

           @Override
           public void setLocale(Locale loc) {
               original.setLocale(loc);
           }

           @Override
           public Locale getLocale() {
               return original.getLocale();
           }

           @Override
           public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
               original.addCookie(cookie);
           }

           @Override
           public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
               return original.containsHeader(name);
           }

           @Override
           public String encodeURL(String url) {
               return original.encodeURL(url);
           }

           @Override
           public String encodeRedirectURL(String url) {
               return original.encodeRedirectURL(url);
           }

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           @Override
           public String encodeUrl(String url) {
               return original.encodeUrl(url);
           }

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           @Override
           public String encodeRedirectUrl(String url) {
               return original.encodeRedirectUrl(url);
           }

           @Override
           public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
               original.sendError(sc, msg);
           }

           @Override
           public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
               original.sendError(sc);
           }

           @Override
           public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
               original.sendRedirect(location);
           }

           @Override
           public void setDateHeader(String name, long date) {
               original.setDateHeader(name, date);
           }

           @Override
           public void addDateHeader(String name, long date) {
               original.addDateHeader(name, date);
           }

           @Override
           public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
               original.setHeader(name, value);
           }

           @Override
           public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
               original.addHeader(name, value);
           }

           @Override
           public void setIntHeader(String name, int value) {
               original.setIntHeader(name, value);
           }

           @Override
           public void addIntHeader(String name, int value) {
               original.addIntHeader(name, value);
           }

           @Override
           public void setStatus(int sc) {
               original.setStatus(sc);
           }

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           @Override
           public void setStatus(int sc, String sm) {
               original.setStatus(sc, sm);
           }

       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

See RequestDumperValve or RequestDumperFilter here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Request_Dumper_Valve
it does what you want.

Comment: RequestDumperFilter does not log the POST payload, only the Headers and URL (including query string)