# HttpServletRequest.getParameter() of spring boot HandlerInterceptor returns null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, handlerinterceptor

I am overriding preHandle() method of Spring boot HandlerInterceptor.
When I am invoking getParameter() method on HttpServletRequest request it is returning null.

```
@Component
@Slf4J
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info("age::{}",request.getParameter("age"));
    
        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

controller class...

```
@RestController
@Slf4J
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test(@RequestBody Person person){
        log.info("in test method");
    }
}
```

dto...

```
@Data
public class Person {
   private Integer age;
}
```

json body....

```
{"age":"34"}
```

output:

```
age:: null
```

Body is present in HttpServletRequest. i have verified it with bufferReader and getContentLength() but not able to access it via getParameter().

I have gone through below stack overflow links

[Logging Payload of POSTs to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528628/logging-payload-of-posts-to-tomcat)

[HttpServletRequest.getParameter() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938780/httpservletrequest-getparameter-returns-null)

http://natch3z.blogspot.com/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html

These all helps to extract the data from request body but it requires a lot of custom code to be written. Is there any solution provided by spring using which directly I can access the param values.

Why getParameter() is returning null and how can we access the data directly?

Comment: `getParameter` reads parameters from the query string or from form data in the body. It does not try to parse JSON body content.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. So I guess the answer that I posted below is the only was through which we can access data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431817/string-string-request-getparameterdata-is-null

Comment: The `@RequestBody` annotated method parameter is a fine solution. You don't need to manually read the request body. Let Spring MVC do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in other way.

I have used IOUtils of apache, **org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils**

```
String data = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
Person person = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, Person.class);
```

this solves my problem but still I feel it to be workaround as getParameter() should return appropriate value for key I think so.