# Modify request message body

Tags: java, servlets, filter

how can I modify the request message body at filters level. Can we change the message body with our custom message using `RequestWrapper`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1561963/174184

Comment: @TJ- - how does that relate to this? I mean, there you read the body, but there is no editing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

However, you don't really modify the original request body; instead, you can return a different body from the request wrapper and the servlet will just work with that.

As for how you do it, just overwrite the `getInputStream()` method of the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and return a modified version of the original `InputStream`.

To make sure you remove any trail of the original body, you may want to overwrite `getReader()` as well. Standard implementations would return some `BufferedReader` over your `InputStream` when asked for a reader, but
there are mock implementations (like the one in spring-test) that don't.

Comment: how can i return a different body for the request

Comment: I tried to answer with edits to my post above: you should overwrite `getInputStream()` (and `getReader()`, so you won't rely on the underlying `HttpServletRequest` implementation behavior).

Comment: I am using async filters to read post request and once i get all the data then i have to forward that data to underlying servlet for processing. How can I do It