# Saving entirety of web requests, Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

I'm working with an API that is not well documented and I am trying to save the requests made to the server so I can better understand the inner workings.

Some preliminary research yielded two possible solutions:

A) Filters

B) Request Dumper Valve

---

Here are some of the areas where I found helpful advice that I didn't understand how to use:

[Logging Payload of POSTs to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528628/logging-payload-of-posts-to-tomcat)

https://coderanch.com/t/484631/application-servers/configure-Tomcat-log-POST-data

---

My problem is not with the solutions that were provided in the above links, it's that I don't understand how to utilize them in Tomcat.

For example, in the first link the OP posts:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    LOG.debug("payload: " + requestWrapper.getRequestBody());
```

> and web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.host.PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Which is great! Except that if I add the code above into my web.xml my localhost TomCat will only return 404, and I have no idea where I should put the Java code as it can't compile on its' own and definitely requires some dependencies.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `doFilter` method belongs in a class that you have to write. The class has to implement the `Filter` interface. There are tutorials which describe this, step-by-step. For example, [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html). The fully qualified name of your class then goes into the `<filter-class>` tag. Regarding the `<filter-mapping>`, your example is filtering everything arriving at `/resources/*`. Your web app almost certainly does not have such a URL pattern. The tutorials should cover this. That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, this tutorial was exactly the kind of content I was searching for!